# How to pass parameters to external webservice from Mule

Tags: parameters, mule

How can I pass parameters to external webservice via mule flow using CFX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you use the [WSDL-CXF connector](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/WSDL+Connectors), you pass parameters as an array of objects in the in-flight Mule message. Only primitives and String can be used in this array.
- Otherwise, if you need to use complex objects as parameters, use the objects you've generated from the WSDL following [this method](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Consuming+Web+Services+with+CXF).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks alot. It worked. I put a transformer to convert my parameters to Object[] array for cxf:jaxws-client as follows.

```
<custom-transformer class="tranformers.ObjectArrayTransformer" doc:name="Java"/>
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8080/WebService/HelloWorldImpl" doc:name="HTTP">
    <cxf:jaxws-client operation="getParamData" serviceClass="miniwebservice.HelloWorld" port="80" doc:name="SOAP"/>
</http:outbound-endpoint>
```